# Transaction hanged on 1 peer, did reset and now balance is 0 transaction is gone

Tags: multibit, btce

I did an transaction to BTCe but it remained on 1 peer for a very long time.
I then reset my blockchain and transactions in Multibit but now the transaction is gone and my balance is 0. The adress on BTCe also says 0.

What can I do?

Comment: The first thing you need to find out is whether or not the transaction completed. You can check on [blockexplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/) or [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/). If it's there, you probably just have to wait for it to get enough confirmations. If it's not there, the funds never moved.

Comment: Thanks I made a new wallet, exported the keys of the old one then imported it in the new one and my balance was back so the funds were indeed never moved.